# PHP email form sends Array instead of variables

Tags: php, email

I'm trying to figure out a basic web email form. I got the code from somewhere and am trying to make the checkboxes options.

The email gets sent but just has Array next to the option.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi and welcome Bryan, whack your code up for us to see (remove any db connection / sensitive data from it)

Comment: If you find correct answer, you should mark it as one! =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sample code will help diagnose the problem.
At a guess I'd say you've got something like

```
$message = "contact from message\r\n";
$message .= $_POST['check'];
```

since `$_POST['check']` is an array, you need to use it like:

```
$message .= implode(', ', $_POST['check']);
```

This will convert the array of selected services options into a comma delimited string.

Comment: Great! thank you! that worked! well when I did $check .= implode(', ', $_POST['check']);

Answer (score 0):

If you are a PHP beginner, you can use [PHP Forms](http://phpforms.net) builder that allows to create professionally looking email forms within just a few minutes. You will only need to make a PHP form by means of an intuitive interface and generate a code that can be easily copied and pasted to any web page.